# Record voice - Actions on Google

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

If possible, how can I allow the user to record a voice when interacting with my app (or action), and then allowing me to perform some actions on that voice record (Convert Speech To Text for example).

I know that I can specify parameters and extract some information, but what if I want to capture everything that the user have said, or just allow the user to record a message in any language and then perform whatever I want to do on on it.

Answer (score 1):

Developers only get the user transcription, not the actual audio that was said.

Comment: Isn't there a way to allow recording? Like how whatsApp uses it (When specifying that we want to send a voice message, it opens a card allowing us to record a message)

Comment: The Actions on Google platform does not support giving developers the audio directly.